# Graphical Grub/Bootloader Menu

Tags: linux, grub, bootloader

Does anyone know of a boot loader that use graphical indicators instead of just a command line menu?
(preferably grub or grub2 compatible, I don't really know much about the, or my, tech stack for boot loading)

I decided I wanted this when I thought back to the mechanic of Appleware's boot-loader, it didn't ask what you wanted to boot from unless you held the alt key. I basically wanted that, save time at boot and just drop my in my primary unless I make an effort to load another. (Windows 8 Takes this approach when "Shutting Down" where it is far less appreciated.)

But along with the desire for less boot selection experience, comes the desire for a prettier boot selector. Feel free to post an answer about how to configure grub to only prompt on held keystroke, knowing that I may not try to implement any solutions that don't also offer graphical interface (I will still accept the answer if it gets significant upvotes).

Comment: What do you mean by a graphical interface (prettier than just a text list)?  At that stage of startup, nothing is loaded yet to handle graphics.  Also, the "automated" aspect is the default behavior.  If you do nothing to select an option, it selects the first one after a few seconds.  Are you talking about just hiding the options?

Comment: @fixer1234 I am out to find a boot loader that would load and operate on a loaded graphical interface. Not  hiding options, but presenting them nicer, and perhaps have some gui to edit entries would be nice but is no current requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I could suggest is BURG. It's based off of GRUB2 and is very beautiful. With a little work, you can learn to customize it and make it exactly as you please. The only big issue with it is that it is a dead project that no one has picked up. I haven't had any issues with it, but I also have a pretty basic boot setup. Mint, Fedora, Slackware, and Windows.

If you're interested, it is available from https://code.google.com/archive/p/burg/